# dotCover code coverage script - GPU process isn't usable

Tags: c#, code-coverage, dotcover

I encountered an issue with my C# code coverage calculation script using dotcover:

```
dotcover c configuration_file.xml
```

Everything was working well until a few days ago when I started getting the following error:

```
The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed : [1113/144351.571:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(431)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.

Test Run Aborted with error System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.Stream.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read7BitEncodedInt()
   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.LengthPrefixCommunicationChannel.NotifyDataAvailable()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.TcpClientExtensions.MessageLoopAsync(TcpClient client, ICommunicationChannel channel, Action`1 errorHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken).
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if so, how did you resolve it?